# Animate height change of TextBox with (TextWrapping=Wrap)

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, word-wrap

How could I animate the `Height` change of a `TextBox` with the `TextWrapping` property set to `Wrap`?

Basically, I'd like to animate the change of height that occurs when writing text and the text overflows on a new line.

And the same for the reverse scenario.

Comment: The question is pretty broad. First thing that comes to mind is to actually have two different `TextBox` elements both bound to the same text, one hidden and one not. Have the hidden one automatically adjust its height due to wrapping, but set the visible one's height explicitly. When the hidden one's height changes, animate the visible one's height to match. I'm sure there are other options; that's just the first that came to mind. Please post a good [mcve] that shows specifically what you've tried already, and explain in detail what specific part you're having trouble with.

Comment: I was just looking for ideas, I haven't done anything yet, I googled it because I'm new to wpf and nothing came to mind, but I haven't found anything. This is why I've asked a question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Your line of approach interests me, I'll gather informations about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally created my own control to do this. It's posted on CodeProject [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1111076/WPF-TextBox-with-Animated-Overflow).

Thanks to **Peter Duniho** for the idea.